# Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be measurable. Prove that {$A\subset\mathbb{R}:f^{-1}(A)\in M$} is a $\sigma-algebra$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I use the following defintion for measurability

Let $f$ be defined on $I=[a,b]$. We say that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable on $I$ if for every $s \in \mathbb{R}$, the set {$x \in I : f(x)>s$} is a Lebesgue measurable set.

I have had trouble understanding the idea that $\emptyset\in $ {$A\subset\mathbb{R}:f^{-1}(A)\in M$}, (where $M$ is the collection of all measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}$). How can we say that {$x \in \emptyset : f(x)>s$} is measurable for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the preimage of the empty set under $f$ is the empty set. Now the empty set is a Lebesgue measurable set. Hence $\emptyset \in M$ which means that it satisfies $\emptyset\subset\mathbb{R}: f^{-1}(\emptyset)\in M$.

The last sentence of your questions refers to the definition of the Lebesgue measurability of $f$. That set is the empty set for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$ hence measurable.

Does the above answer your question?